# Strange functions when profiling Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am currently optimizing my HTML/Javascript game. And I am using the profiler on google chrome to get some information about what functions are using the most time. Everything seems to be fine. Except whenever the game stutters/lags, I can see a function in the profiler that is not part of my code. I looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G5pQ.png).

Function like these appeared numerous times. And sometimes they take up to 100ms, which is causing my game to stutter a lot. How can I find the source of these functions?

EDIT: My game contains a lot of functions like these:

```
socket.on('1', function (data) {
    ...
});
```

And my Gameloop looks like this:

```
var lastTime = 0;
function prepareUpdate(callback) {
    var now = Date.now();
    var nextTime = mathMax(lastTime + (1000 / targetFPS), now);
    return setTimeout(function() { 
        callback(lastTime = nextTime); 
    }, nextTime - now);
};
function callUpdate() {
    prepareUpdate(callUpdate);
    updateGameLoop();
};
callUpdate();
```

Are these considered harmful?

Comment: How can you be so sure it is not part of your game?

Comment: are you using any anonymous functions in your code?

Comment: Callback functions are often anonymous so that might be a one of them, just name all your callback and you should be able to get a clearer picture of what get called. It also help to profile the code base before it is compressed so you get the full function names instead of 1 character function names.

Comment: could be an IIFE aswell...

Comment: It is not directly in my code. I may be something that my code is referencing: library or something of that nature. My question is; how do I know where it is from?

Comment: @SidneydeVries, `socket.on('1', function (data) {` and `return setTimeout(function() { ` are both the start of anonymous functions so it could be either of those. I suggest doing what GillesC suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what GilliesC suggested, naming your anonymous functions could be done like so:

```
socket.on('1', function onOne(data) {
    ...
});
```

Where onOne is just some random name for the function (that isn't defined anywhere else)

Comment: After checking again. It seems that the function is called from runtime.js
What is that?
Is that my compiled code?

Comment: It could be a chrome extension if it isn't part of your code base

Comment: It is called swiffy runtime. I think that has something to do with flash though.